# Missing the last element when reading input

Tags: c

I should be able to read input like this:

> 0 50 50 100 30 40 30 50 10 100 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90.

My current implementation does not read the number before -1. Therefore, in the first process "100" is missing and in the second process "90" is missing. I have a struct `Process` that I want to receive the input. How can I fix this issue? Where is the problem?

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    int arrival; 
    int numofProcesses; 
    int *cpu_times; 
    int *io_times; 
} Process;   

void readInput(Process *queue, int *rear)
{
    while (true)
    {   
        int arrival_time;
        int cpu;
        int io;
        if (scanf("%d", &arrival_time) == EOF)
            break;    

        int *cpu_times = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
        int *io_times = (int *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
        int num_of_bursts = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            scanf("%d", &cpu_time);
            scanf("%d", &io_time);
    /* end the process when encountering -1*/
            if (cpu_time == -1 || io_time == -1)
                break;
    /* add the input to the data in struct */ 
            cpu_times[num_of_bursts] = cpu_burst;
            io_times[num_of_bursts] = io_time;
            num_of_bursts++;
        }

        if (num_of_bursts > 0) {
            Process nP = {arrival_time, num_of_bursts, cpu_times, io_times};

        arrival_queue[++(*rear)] = nP;
    }
    else {
        free(cpu_times);
        free(io_times);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the `100` and `90`, which don't have valid value for `io_burst`? You should add some code to do what you want to do.

Comment: It *is* relevant: please show the *actual* data not "something like my data".

Comment: If the user input some non-digit input then the condition `if (scanf("%d", &arrival_time) == EOF)` will be false, and you will end up an infinite loop. Also, *always* check what `scanf` returns, even when it seems to not be needed.

Comment: You also don't have a check for the inner loop going out of bounds of the memory you allocate.

Comment: @WeatherVane what are you saying?

Comment: And how are you *calling* this function? Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. (Where the indentation is "correct" and consistent.)

Comment: @travxx, the example input you provide is essential for us to understandf the nature of the problem.  If what you provide is not representative of the data you actually want the program to process, then how are we supposed to understand the nature of the issue?

Comment: Sorry, you deleted the comment that said your example wasn't exact, and wasn't important.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think I have clearly explained the nature of this issue which is that it does not add the number before -1 to the bursts. If you that with any set of numbers that is going to happen. So clearly you are concentrating on something that is not important.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: In that case, @travxx, taking the input presented as being one you expect the program to handle successfully, please answer MikeCAT's initial question: what behavior do you *expect*, here?  Your program for the most part does not process individual numbers.  It processes *pairs*.  The 100 and 90 are each paired with a -1, so what do you expect the program to do with them?

Comment: Oh and when you [edit] your question then please give us the actual assignment you have. Especially important is the *description* of the input. Then example you show just doesn't give us enough context.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other comments (e.g. about writing out of bounds, not checking return values by scanf), your problem might be as simple as that you're always reading two values, but relying on a separator of a single value, so you get desynchronised in your input stream.  Make your terminator -1, -1 and you'll probably be ok.

Comment: This is likely correct. The OP is reading `-1` into `cpu_burst` and then the next `20` into `io_burst`, getting the input out of synch.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix this issue? Where is the problem?

The main issue is that you are unconditionally reading the bulk of the input as *pairs* of numbers:

> ```
>             scanf("%d", &cpu_burst);
>             scanf("%d", &io_burst);
>     /* end the process when encountering -1*/
>             if (cpu_burst == -1 || io_burst == -1)
>                 break;
> ```

... but the delimiter marking the end of each list of pairs is a *single* number.  When a -1 is read for either number, the other number read is discarded.

Additionally, unless the items you refer to are *intended* to be ignored, your example input must be malformed.  Although most of the data consist of pairs, a leading single integer is expected for the `arrival_time`, so there should be an odd number of integers for each `Process` (excluding the -1).  Your example input has an even number of items for each `Process`.

As a side issue, you also do not consistently watch for end-of-file on the input or handle invalid input well.  That's not responsible for the behavior you describe, but you should form good habits now, when you're learning, because it's a lot harder to break bad habits later.

Supposing that you don't want to or can't change the format of the data, you need to be smarter about how you read it.  Something more like this, for example:

```
            int result;

            result = scanf("%d", &cpu_burst);
            if (result == EOF) {
                // this is an input format error, but possibly a benign one
                fprintf(stderr, "warning: process data unexpectedly terminated by EOF\n");
                break;
            } else if (result != 1) {
                // this is an input format error
                fprintf(stderr, "input format error: invalid character in process data\n");
                break;
            } else if (cpu_burst == -1) {  // end of process
                // don't consume the next number, if any
                break;
            }

            result = scanf("%d", &io_burst);
            if (result == EOF) {
                // this is an input format error
                fprintf(stderr, "input format error: process data unexpectedly truncated\n");
                break;
            } else if (result != 1) {
                // this is an input format error
                fprintf(stderr, "input format error: invalid character in process data\n");
                break;
            } else if (io_burst == -1) {
                // this is an input format error
                fprintf(stderr, "input format error: no io_burst for cpu_burst '%d'\n", cpu_burst);
                // end of process; the bare cpu_burst is ignored
                break;
            }
```

There are ways to make that less repetitive, but for robustness, yes, your program really needs to do all that.